# getters/setters for a python class that inherits dict

Tags: python, dictionary, getter-setter

To aid in serializing to JSON, I commonly build a class that inherits from the python dict class.  If the class is supposed to have specific fields, I want there to be methods to get & set.

Currently, I construct a class like:

```
class MyRequest(dict):
    def __init__(self, firstName=None, lastName=None):
        self['firstName'] = firstName
        self['lastName'] = lastName

    def get_firstName(self):
        return self['firstName']
    def set_firstName(self, firstName):
        self['firstName'] = firstName

    def get_lastName(self):
        return self['lastName']
    def set_lastName(self, lastName):
        self['lastName'] = lastName
```

But this is really cumbersome to work with.  Since the underlying 'storage' is a dictionary, I can't just access fields like

```
myReq.firstName = "Foo"
print myReq.lastName
```

But is there a way to get to there while still keeping the dict backing?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`Storage`](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/gluon/storage.py#34), [`Namespace`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/argparse.py#l1140)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do what you want. Use properties:

```
class MyRequest(dict):
    def __init__(self, firstName=None, lastName=None):
        self['firstName'] = firstName
        self['lastName'] = lastName

    @property
    def firstName(self):
        return self['firstName']

    @firstName.setter
    def firstName(self, firstName):
        self['firstName'] = firstName

    @property
    def lastName(self):
        return self['lastName']

    @lastName.setter
    def lastName(self, lastName):
        self['lastName'] = lastName

request = MyRequest('John', 'Connor')
print request.firstName, request.lastName
request.firstName = 'Sarah'
print request.firstName, request.lastName
```

Comment: There's almost no good reason nowadays to use `UserDict`. Subclassing `dict` works fine.

Comment: Yes, thanks. `UserDict` is left for backward compatibility with python 2.2 and older.

Comment: There are actually many reasons in SO that suggest staying away from properties when you want to do what the OP suggests. example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900940/pythonic-alternative-to-dict-style-setter

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
class MyRequest(dict):
    def __init__(self, firstName=None, lastName=None):
        self['firstName'] = firstName
        self['lastName'] = lastName

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value
```

Note that this may come back to haunt you, in the case where one of your attributes has the same name as a `dict` method (e.g. `update`). In that case, getting the attribute will return the method, and setting it will overwrite the method. This may be difficult to debug.

Comment: You could use hasattr to return the actual dict attribute if it exists, or try and return the actual dict attribute and catch the exception to override it.

Comment: Or you could use composition rather than inheritance.