# Pythonic alternative to dict-style setter?

Tags: python, coding-style, setter, getter, getter-setter

People tend to consider getters and setters un-Pythonic, prefering to use `@property` instead.  I'm currently trying to extend the functionality of a class that uses `@property` to support a dict:

```
class OldMyClass(object):
    @property
    def foo(self):
       return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self.side_effect(value)
        self._foo = value

class NewMyClass(object):
    @property
    def foo(self, key):  # Invalid Python
        return self._foo[key]

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, key, value):  # Invalid Python
        self.side_effect(key, value)
        self._foo[key] = value
```

Of course, I could create some helper classes to deal with this, but it seems like just writing setter/getter functions that take a key and value would be much simpler. But is there a more Pythonic way to do this refactor?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  What is `foo.setter`?  Normally that would only work if you had already previously defined a getter called `foo`.  Also, how are you intending to use the resulting object?  How is the `key` supposed to be used?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't include the getter because I didn't think it was really relevant. I'll add it for clarity. I don't understand your question about how I'm intending to use the resulting object

Comment: What I mean, is what is the code you intend to use to set the key/value?  With a normal property you would do `obj.prop = value`.  What do you want to do instead?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to do obj.prop[key]=value

Comment: Then why do you need a property at all?  Just make `prop` an ordinary dictionary.

Comment: Because I need the side effects to happen when I do the setting (the self.side_effect(key, value) part of the example code)

Comment: Then write a method `obj.set_key(key, value)`

Comment: Ok, that was what I was asking. Python frowns on setters but you're saying in this case it's the right choice

Comment: Yeah. Or you could add a `__setitem__` on your class if you want to be able to do obj[key] = value and execute some code when the setting occur, as suggested by BrenBarn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is not a case for properties.  Properties are for allowing `obj` (or rather, its class) to customize the behavior of `obj.prop = value`.  If you want to customize `obj.prop[key] = value`, then you need to handle that not in `obj` but in `obj.prop`, which means you need to make `obj.prop` be a custom class.  What you want here is to create a custom class with a `__setitem__`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._vals = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        do_side_effect(key, val)
        self._vals[key] = val
```

Then in your MyClass's `__init__`, do `self.foo = Foo()`.

If you want this dict-like object to know what its parent object is (e.g., because the side effect should take place on the parent, then pass the parent as an argument to Foo:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self._vals = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        parent.do_side_effect(key, val)
        self._vals[key] = val
```

And then in `MyClass.__init__` you do `self.foo = Foo(self)`.

With regard to getters/setters, what you're doing is not a typical getter/setter.  The kind of thing that is discouraged is things like `getSomeProp()` and `setSomeProp(value)`, where there is a separate method for each property that you get/set.  In your example, you're describing something different, which is a generalized get/set mechanism for setting key-value pairs (which presumably have some meaning for the object's behavior).  Having a method `setPair(key, value)` is not any worse than having a method called `doSomething(arg1, arg2)`.  Here you have an extra parameter, so your task doesn't fit into the simple pattern of `obj.key = value`.  You also have an extra layer of indirection if you want the key/value in`obj.prop[key] = value` to "know about" `obj`; in an assignment like `obj.prop[key] = value`, the key and value are one step removed from `obj` and interact directly only with `prop`.

You could also do it with a simple method as John Smith Optional suggests.  Whether you want to do it that way or with a custom object like I described depends on how you want the API set up.  There can be readability benefits to having the code built around custom "data-holding" classes like the one I outlined here, but it does make the implementation a bit more complex.